# JQuery hover, click and touch combination

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, touch, mouseevent

I would like to show and hide an element using **hover, click and touch** events. The idea behind this is that you will be able to use the same element for touch devices, devices that use a mouse and  combination devices, like laptops that have touch. So I would need to **combine mouse and touch input**.
The problem is that the events influence eachother and multiple events are fired when I use touch causing the element to be shown and hidden over and over again.

How can I get the behaviour I want;

- toggle on click and touch
- show on mouseenter
- hide on mouseout

I have tried multiple implementations such as the following and none seem to be stable.

```
 $("#showMe").hide();
 $(document).on('touchstart click mouseenter mouseout', '#thingToTrigger', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    if (event.handled !== true) {
        $("#showMe").toggle(1000);
        event.handled = true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Here is the **JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9305f9d7/**

Answer (score 0):

The main thing you want to achieve is to disable default behaviour.

You can add listeners for the various events, and prevent the others at the beginning of the event listeners. e.g.:

```
$(document).on('touchstart click', '#thingToTrigger', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //Do Touch specific stuff, e.g. toggle()
});

$(document).on('mouseenter', '#thingToTrigger', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //Do Mouseenter specific stuff, e.g. show()
});

$(document).on('mouseout', '#thingToTrigger', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //Do Mouseout specific stuff, e.g. hide()
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add class on click of that element.

```
e.g. #div1 and #div2

$("#div1").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
    $("#div2").show();
});

$("#div1").on("mouseenter",function(){
    $("#div2").show();
});

$("#div1").on("mouseout",function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("clicked")==false) $("#div2").hide();
});
```

Hope this help.

Comment: This would work with or without the toggled class, if I didn't want to include touch. The problem is not that the hovering events also trigger a click event but that the touch event triggers a mouseenter event, followed by a mouseout event. Adding a class to solve this issue would be the same as adding a variable to keep track of the showing and hiding. This does not seem like a very elegant solution to me.